# Does the UserMap.xml file needed for automated import of a CRM2011 tennant need to include the disabled users?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

We are running CRM in an enterprise style environment, with 4 environments that changes need to propagate through before entering production.  We are also dealing with a very large dynamic dataset and complex logic implemented in SQL server working from this dataset, along side the CRM components.

Our environments are as follows:

1. Development
2. Test
3. Staging
4. Production

To facilitate development, testing, etc we restore our dataset and CRM from Production back to the various environments as needed, in Development we restore very frequently (usually nightly).

One of the challenges we have encountered with this is that when restoring the CRM tennant automatically using the powershell tools, we need an accurate UserMap XML file available which contains all the users existing in our production environment.  Currently whenever a new user is added to production we our automated restore fails and we have to manually update the file.

In looking to automate file creation, I was unable to find the answer to the following question:  Does the UserMap.xml file need to also include disabled users?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this we produced a new UserMap.xml file from the production environment and manually checked to confirm that in face Disabled users ARE included in the UserMap.xml file.